# Writing Values From Python into Excel

Tags: python, excel, concatenation

What I am trying to do is to get this line of code to work by putting a price from Yahoo Finance for a stock into a spreadsheet. I have asked quite a few people and I have researched the issue but I haven't gotten it to work.

This is the trouble line of code:

```
ws.cell(1,i+1).value = str.replace(price','price')
```

I get errors likes, "replace' requires a 'str' object but received a 'list' or 'int' object has no attributes everytime I modify it. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

import urllib
import re

from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter

wb = Workbook()

dest_filename = r'empty_book.xlsx'

ws = wb.create_sheet()

ws.title = 'Stocks'
symbolslist = ["aapl","spy","goog","nflx"] 

i=0
while i<len(symbolslist):
    #counts each object as 1 in the list
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+symbolslist[i]+"&q1=1"
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_'+symbolslist[i]+'">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    print "The price of", symbolslist[i], " is ", price 
    ws.cell(1,i+1).value = str.replace(price','price')
    i+=1


wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

Importing the CSV module is better than using Excel for data analysis because it is open source friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't even think you need the EXCEL API to do this, you are merely work offline, so write the finance stock price using CSV format, and then open the csv file using EXCEL. like this (psudo code, not exact one ):

```
with( f=open( "a.csv" ) ):
    f.writeline( ",".join(l) );
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea...but where do I put that code? I want the Excel file for manipulating the data later.

Answer (score 0):

1. `re.findall` return a list object, you may want to get the first object of the list.
2. you can only use `str.replace` from an string object, such as`price.replace('a', 'b')`
3. should use `ws.cell('F5')` instead of `ws.cell(1,1)` to access one cell.